# Python multithreading : manager dict not serializable

Tags: python, json, serialization, dictionary, multiprocessing

I managed to put multithreading in a python script. I use the manager of the multiprocessing module to create and share a dictionnay upon multiple threads.

At the end of my script, i want to ouput the dict as json in a file, so i do :

```
output = open(args.file,'w')
output.write(json.dumps(data))
```

But i go an error, saying me that the manager dict is not serializable :

```
TypeError: <DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x2364210> is not JSON serializable
```

What is the clever way of serialize my dict ? Do i have to copy-paste the key-values into another -usual- one ?

Answer (score 4):

### If the dict values are all serializable

It looks like simply passing the `DictProxy` through the `dict` constructor allows you to serialize the data to JSON. The example below is from Python 3.6:

```
>>> import multiprocessing, json
>>> m = multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> d = m.dict()
>>> d["foo"] = "bar"
>>> d
<DictProxy object, typeid 'dict' at 0x2a4d630>
>>> dict(d)
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> json.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
TypeError: Object of type 'DictProxy' is not JSON serializable
>>> json.dumps(dict(d))
'{"foo": "bar"}'
```

As you can see, while `d` is a `DictProxy`, using `json.dumps(dict(d))` instead of `json.dumps(d)` allowed the data to be serialized. If you are using `json.dump`, the same applies.

### If some dict values are also DictProxies

Unfortunately, the above method does not work if a value in the `DictProxy` is also a `DictProxy`. Such a value is created in this example:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> m = multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> d = m.dict()
>>> d["foo"] = m.dict()
```

The solution is to extend the `json.JSONEncoder` class to handle `DictProxy` objects, like so:

```
>>> import multiprocessing, json
>>> class JSONEncoderWithDictProxy(json.JSONEncoder):
...     def default(self, o):
...             if isinstance(o, multiprocessing.managers.DictProxy):
...                     return dict(o)
...             return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
...
>>> m = multiprocessing.Manager()
>>> d = m.dict()
>>> d["foo"] = m.dict()
>>> d["foo"]["bar"] = "baz"
>>> json.dumps(d, cls=JSONEncoderWithDictProxy)
'{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}'
>>> # This also works:
>>> JSONEncoderWithDictProxy().encode(d)
'{"foo": {"bar": "baz"}}'
```

When the JSON encoder encounters a `DictProxy`, it will convert it to a `dict` and then encode it. For more information, see the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder.default).

Answer (score 0):

... "pretty" simple.

I saw [this answer](http://bugs.python.org/issue9733) of an issue.

I have to use iter() on the keys of the dictionnary to create a new "usual" one that can be serialized.